# AWS CLI: Is there way to find number of objects stored per day in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

As the title suggests, I am interested to know how that can be done.
If not CLI, what are other options?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). It can generate a daily inventory file that you could inspect, or even query it with Amazon Athena.

Comment: Or [bucket metrics in CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)?